# How to define/pass the entity manager for sonata-admin

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I followed [this tutorial](http://symfony2.ylly.fr/sonataadminbundle-fosuserbundle-have-a-good-base-project-jordscream/) to install SonataAdmin with FOSUserBundle.

Now i keep getting this Error Message:
No entity manager defined for class Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User

But how do i set/pass the EntityManager?
I haven't found anything about configuring it or any hint on what this error means.
Any help anyone?

---

**Edit #1:**

As asked for, here is what i have in my config.yml for sonata so far:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
```

---

**Edit #2:**

I added the entity manager configuration part for Doctrine2 ORM Admin thou it is mentioned in the Documentation that if left null, it should just use the default. Still, it doesn't solve my problem.

```
sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    # default value is null, so doctrine uses the value defined in the configuration
    entity_manager: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
```

---

**Edit #3:**
I did set auto_mapping to true as well, even thou that also is true by default.
Still no Solution to this Problem.

Comment: post your config.yml (at least parts related to sonata, doctrine and fos)

Comment: Good point, thou i don't really have much in there :(

Comment: Does your doctrine ORM `auto_mapping` option is set to true? If not, you have to manually tell which classes Doctrine must handle as entities.

Comment: Yes it (auto_mapping) is active.

Comment: @Damien: Any idea on how i do tell doctrine this manually ever since the auto_mapping has no effect?

Comment: @AndreschSerj Look at the `mappings:` key here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was missing in my config.yml was:

```
doctrine:
  [...]
  orm:
    [...]
    entity_managers:
      default:
        mappings:
          ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
          SonataUserBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use

`php app/console sonata:admin:generate`

it requests for fully qualified model class, so you'd write something like:

`\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\DemoEntity`

the problem is, that when generator creates service for you it adds line:

`arguments: [~, \Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\DemoEntity, AcmeDemoBundle:DemoEntityAdmin]`

That breaks it.

It works with:

`arguments: [~, Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\DemoEntity, AcmeDemoBundle:DemoEntityAdmin]`

Notice missing "\" before Acme\Demo....

Comment: i gave up on the Admin Bundle long time ago. Thanks for the delated answer to an already answered question thou. In my next symfony project i will try your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem.

Make sure you easy-extended the SonataUserBundle:

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle
```

and are loading it in AppKernel.php

```
new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
```

See documentation here:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/installation.rst

Then the automapping is enough and you don't need to define manual mapping.