# Symfony Sonata Media Bundle

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sonata

**Situation**

I am using Symfony (and MongoDB as DB) and want to integrate the Sonata Media Bundle in to the Sonata Admin bundle. Prior to adding the media bundle, everything was working great.

I followed the guide on the Sonata site and have appeared to setup the media admin bundle correctly; please see config below

config.yml

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: test_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
              ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
              SonataMediaBundle: ~
            auto_mapping: true
...
sonata_media:
    # if you don't use default namespace configuration
    #class:
    #    media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
    #    gallery: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
    #    gallery_has_media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
    default_context: default
    db_driver: doctrine_mongodb # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr
    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}
```

Company.php Document class

```
namespace AppBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $title;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $slug;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Document\Media", mappedBy="image")
     */
    protected $logo;
```

companyadmin.php

```
->add('logo', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(), array('link_parameters' => array('context' => 'default')))
```

**Issue**

Now, whenever I go in to the company admin interface, I'm greeted by the message "No document manager defined for class Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\PersistentCollection"

I'm relatively new to Symfony and I don't really see what is going wrong. Please can you help give a poke in the right direction. If I remove the logo from admin, naturally it starts working again. Please help, really clueless here

Answer (score 0):

If you use: **auto_mapping: true** you don't need document manager default mappings, otherwise you have to add in your config file:

```
orm:
#        auto_mapping: true

    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
           # naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            mappings:
                ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                YourBundle: ~
```

- Check in AppKernel.php for the ApplicationSonataMediaBundle() instance run the command:
- run app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Take a look to this question too:

[How to define/pass the entity manager for sonata-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800320/how-to-define-pass-the-entity-manager-for-sonata-admin)